# How did Palpatine create Vader's suit in such short notice?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, darth-sidious

In the movie, it is shown that the operation and suit-up of Vader begins shortly after Palpatine finds him. I was reading an article explaining Vader's armor and it shows that a lot of thought has been made into every single detail of the armor, like the the edges of the helmet being made to deflect blows to the shoulders, the breathing aparathus, the whatever in the feet, eyes and so on.

Furthermore the helmet and shoulders are made from durasteel (among other metals) and the hand is forged from sith amulets.

The question is simple: How the force did Palpatine have such a suit lying around ? It looks like something which will take a while to create even if all the materials are avaliable.

Comment: At least the clumsy design of the suit would be in accordance with a hasty assembly.

Comment: A lot of force users could see quite a bit of the future. Maybe he did too and was having a plan for such occasion already.

Comment: Not to forget another component of the suit: The cape!! ;-)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Now I've got a vision of Palpatine staying up late, slaving away at his sewing machine...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the [novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_%28novel%29), the surgery on Anakin/Vader took "***many days***" rather than the few minutes we see in the film;

> In the newly renamed Emperor Palpatine Surgical Reconstruction Center
>   on Coruscant, a hypersophisticated prototype Ubrikkian DD-13 surgical
>   droid moved away from the project that it and an enhanced FX-6 medical
>   droid had spent many days rebuilding.

The armour itself (according to the Star Wars novels "Light and Dark" and "Tales of the Jedi") is largely based on existing designs for [Sith Droids](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Elite_Warbot) and [General Grievous'](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous) armour, details of which we can assume Sidious would have had ready access to.

So, The Emperor had **plenty of time**, access to the most **sophisticated medical facilities** in the galaxy, **unlimited resources**, **forbidden Sith plans** as well as being able to use the **Dark Side of the Force** to help construct anything he couldn't buy off-the-shelf.

Comment: And with all that he couldn't soundproof the heavy breathing noise?

Comment: @Oldcat - Have you seen the price of cork these days? And that's not even taking into account the shipping costs to have something fed-ex'd to a galaxy far, far away.

Comment: Just what I was thinking. The movie skipped to the end.